# Passing parameter in callback

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to pass a parameter in a callback, but from the original calling function, and with the stipulation below, e.g. given:

```
function foo() {
  var p = 5;
  getDataFromServer(callBackFunction);
}

function callBackFunction(data) {
  // I need value of 'p' here
  ...
}

function getDataFromServer(callback) {
  // gets data from server
  callback.call();
}
```

***The catch is that I don't want to change the function getDataFromServer(),*** (i.e. allowing it to accept another parameter.)

Is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: The `.call` is rather useless if you don't provide any arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and this is good to know.

```
function foo() {
  var p = 5;
  getDataFromServer(function(){
     callBackFunction(p)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use a closure to do this.

However, it's hard to give code for this because your example isn't clear.

My guess is that you want something like this:

```
function foo() {
  var p = 5;
  getDataFromServer(callBackFunction(p));
}

function callBackFunction(p) {
  var closureOverP = function(data) {... something with p ...};
  return closureOverP;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So a simple anon function won't do?

```
function foo() 
{ 
   var p = 5;

   getDataFromServer( function() 
                      {
                          callBackFunction( p ); 
                      } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Definitely possible and I would say good practice with functional programming languages.  But you call the function like this:

```
function getDataFromServer(callback) {
  // gets data from server
  callback();
}
```

Comment: Note that javascript is more typically described as a multi-paradigm or imperative/object-oriented language, with functional capabilities.